# Renaming the schematic variables

Tags: isabelle

Is there a way to rename the schematic variables of a theorems?
For instance in can we rename `?P` and `?Q` in `impI:(?P ⟹ ?Q) ⟹ ?P ⟶ ?Q` to `?u` and `?v` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate the free variables of the theorem with variables of the right name which are locally fixed e.g., using a `for` clause. Upon generalisation, they will become schematic variables with the right names. So, `impI[where ?P=u and ?Q=v for u v]` should do the job.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!